# Pyside6 - How to avoid QBasicTimer warnings and segmentaion faults with QThreadPool multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pyside6

I followed [this guide](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyside6-applications-qthreadpool/) for multithreading in pyside with `QThreadPool`. I have a few instances of workers for jobs that will, and also could potentially take a long time. For example:

```
def load_bucket_dir(self):
    worker = Worker(UIFunctions.update_bucket_tree, self)
    worker.signals.finished.connect(lambda: widgets.browse_s3_dir.setEnabled(True))
    self.threadpool.start(worker)
```

This function will fetch a user's specified s3 bucket and display the contents in a QTreeWidget. This uses OIDC authentication, which takes a few seconds to complete.

Example 2:

```
def load_bucket_preview(self):
    if self.ui.local_dir.text() and self.ui.s3_dir.text():
        worker = Worker(UIFunctions.update_bucket_preview, self)
        self.threadpool.start(worker)
```

This function displays a preview of files to be uploaded to their s3 bucket depending on the selected files. The speed of this function depends on how many files are selected.

My issue is that whenever a worker is started, I get warnings like these:

```
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
QBasicTimer::start: Timers cannot be started from another thread
QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

And then eventually I get a segmentation fault (either immediately or after some time). The guide I linked didn't specify how to run multiple workers, so I'm assuming I've done something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are `load_bucket_dir` and `load_bucket_preview` running from the UI thread, or from your worker threads? If they're running from your worker threads, you need to have the signal live on a UI-thread object and the workers need to `.emit` to the signal to tell them what to do.

For example,

```py
class MyApplication(QApplication):
    run_task = Signal(typing.Callable)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        run_task.connect(lambda task: task())
```

and then to run a task you'd call `QApplication.instance().run_task.emit(the_task)`, where `the_task` is a `Callable`.